# Oracle 9i Sub query

Tags: oracle

Hi Can any one help me out of this query forming logic

```
SELECT C.CPPID, c.CPP_AMT_MANUAL  
FROM CPP_PRCNT CC,CPP_VIEW c 
WHERE 
  CC.CPPYR IN (
    SELECT C.YEAR FROM CPP_VIEW_VIEW C WHERE  UPPER(C.CPPNO) = UPPER('123')
    AND C.CPP_CODE       ='CPP000000000053'
    and TO_CHAR(c.CPP_DATE,'YYYY/Mon')='2012/Nov'
    )
  AND UPPER(C.CPPNO) = UPPER('123')
  AND C.CPP_CODE       ='CPP000000000053'
  and TO_CHAR(c.CPP_DATE,'YYYY/Mon') =  '2012/Nov';
```

Please Correct me if i formed wrong query structure, in terms of query Performance and Standards. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What exactly is required? Are you facing problems in executing this query or you want the logic to be changed? If so, what exactly is tried to be achieved?

Comment: Hi Am seeing the redudancy in where clauses, so i need to simply that, so is it possible to change it? i have used the conditions twice

Answer (score 1):

If you have some indexes or partitioned tables I would not use functions on columns but on variables, to be able to use indexes/select partitions.

Also I use ANSI 92 SQL syntax. You don't specify(or not directly) a join contition between cpp_prcnt and cpp_view so it is actually a cartesian product(cross join)

```
SELECT C.CPPID, c.CPP_AMT_MANUAL  
FROM CPP_PRCNT CC
CROSS JOIN CPP_VIEW c 
WHERE 
  CC.CPPYR IN (
    SELECT C.YEAR 
    FROM CPP_VIEW_VIEW C 
    WHERE  C.CPPNO = '123'
      AND C.CPP_CODE       ='CPP000000000053'
      AND trunc(c.CPP_DATE,'MM')=to_date('2012/Nov','YYYY/Mon')
    )
    AND  C.CPPNO = '123'
    AND C.CPP_CODE       ='CPP000000000053'
    AND trunc(c.CPP_DATE,'MM')=to_date('2012/Nov','YYYY/Mon')
```

If you show us the definition of cpp_view_view(seems to be a view over cpp_view), the definition(if simple) of CPP_VIEW and what you're trying to achieve, I bet there are more things to be improved/fixed.

Comment: I have used the conditions twice, Is it possible to simplfy that

Comment: If the conditions go in fact to same table then yes, you can use it only once, but I don't know what is behind the views. You're putting those conditions on distinct objects so I don't know the logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could improve:

- if possible, get rid of the UPPER() in the comparison - this will render any indices useless. If that's not possible, consider a function-based index on UPPER(CPPNO)
- do not convert your DATE column to a string to compare it with a string - do it the other way round (i.e. convert your string to a date => only one conversion needed instead of one per table row, use of indices possible)
- play around with EXISTS instead of IN, as suggested by Dileep - might be faster